# Skip column with django-tables2

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I want to avoid the ID being displayed.

I am probably missing something obvious, but I can not find int in the [documentation](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html)

I have tried explicitly listing all columns except the ones I want to skip by using:

```
class Meta:
    model = Campaign
    sequence = ("name", "vendor_name", "vendor_email")
```

But the row id is still being shown. How can I prevent that?

Answer (score 0):

I have also tried [exclude](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#Table.Meta.exclude), and it did not work.

The solution was to specify both sequence (for the ordering) and [fields](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/pages/api-reference.html#Table.Meta.fields) (for exhaustive listing).